# How can I stop webdriver execution till my condition satisfy

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am doing automation for one application and need little help .

Scenario is in our application when we update/add something we are showing Loading image till it complete process. And in my webdriver it is not able to find next element until this loading image completes.

So I want to set condition like till there is loading image , stop execution and dont try to find next element , once loading image hide then find for next element. so How here I can stop web driver execution till loading image there.

I am trying something like :

```
WebElement loading = driver.findElement(By.id(AppConstants.loadingimg));

    while(loading.isDisplayed()){

        //What to put here to stop web driver execution for a while

    }
```

I already tried all type of **WAIT** but not working for me in proper way so I want solution with above condition.

Comment: There is quite a good overview on the possible options in the documentation: http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/

Comment: @Nitek - I know buddy but I tried that already and does not fit for my application.. Thanks..

Comment: Can you then please explain a little bit further what the problem was and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> //What to put here to stop web driver execution for a while

As you said you already tried all type of **WAIT** and it's not working , So 
In order to stop execution for a while you can make your  thread to `SLEEP`

```
try{
Thread.sleep(timeYouWantToWait);  // time in millis
}catch(InterruptedException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you mean to say that I should pass thread.sleep in body part of while?